# For Rails, how to access or print out config variables (as experiment or test / debugging)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, in `config/environments/production.rb` in a Rails 3 app, there is

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

and many variables.  How can they be all printed out as a whole (perhaps in an object, instead of specifying each one-by-one) (print out in a view, such as FooController#index), just for looking into what types of values are available and to see what they are set to?

Also, how to print out the values in the `.yml` files (as a hash and/or in some config object?) and in `config/initializers`, such as for

```
MyAppFoo::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

I found that we can print out the content of

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
```

but not

```
ActionController::Base.configurations
```

are there ways to print out all info of the MVC components?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Most of the Rails config stuff can be accessed through:

```
Rails.application.config.<your_variable>
```

With regards to printing out the values of .yml files in config, you'd have to do that yourself becuase Rails will only load up the values for the current environment from `database.yml`, and any custom yml config files will be just that - custom. Here's one way you could load them all up...

```
all_configs = []
Dir[Rails.root.join("config/*.yml")].each {|f| all_configs << YAML.load_file(f) }
```

With regards to settings set in initializers, if it's a Rails config option (such as the session store which you've given as an example), then it will be available through `Rails.application.config`. If not, (for example configuration for a gem) then you will have to manually find those settings from the gem classes.

Comment: The whole `Rails::Application::Configuration` object: `<% logger.debug "--- config: #{Rails.application.config.inspect}" %>`. A specific shallow variable: `<% logger.debug "--- serve_static_assets: #{Rails.application.config.serve_static_assets}" %>`. `assets` OrderedOptions: `<% logger.debug "--- assets: #{Rails.application.config.assets}" %>`. Specific option: `<% logger.debug "--- precompile: #{Rails.application.config.assets.precompile}" %>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `AppName::Application.config` (where `AppName` is the name of your application) to access the `Rails::Application::Configuration` object.

```
$ AppName::Application.config == Rails.application.config
true
```

Answer (score 3):

In modern (Rails 6, 7) versions, you can just do

```
Rails.configuration.<your_variable>
```

Because

```
Rails.application.config == Rails.configuration
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Like idlefingers pointed out, for newer versions of rails, `Rails.application.config.my_variable` should get you what you're looking for.

However, if that doesn't work because you're stuck with an older version of Rails (2.3, etc) you can use the `ENV` constant, like so: `ENV['my_variable']`