# Get environment settings in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some email setting in development.rb which i want to access in my controller.

Settings in `development.rb` are:

```
config.notify_submited_transaction = 'anil@swiftsetup.com,anildbest83@gmail.com'
config.notify_approved_transaction = 'anil@swiftsetup.com'
```

In my controller/action I am trying this:

```
  @to = Rails.env.notify_submited_transaction
  @subject = 'AM - Vendor Submitted Transaction'
  AmMailer.vendor_submited_transaction(@to, @subject, current_user).deliver
```

This though results in error:

```
  undefined method `notify_submited_transaction'
```

I am not sure how to get config value I've set.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to access :

```
Rails.application.config.notify_submited_transaction
Rails.application.config.notify_approved_transaction
```

Seems similar to : [For Rails, how to access or print out config variables (as experiment or test / debugging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288476/for-rails-how-to-access-or-print-out-config-variables-as-experiment-or-test)

Comment: Vik, when application deployed to production, it will pick config values form production.rb automatically, right?

Comment: yup, as per the environment it will load all the settings of your environment file , but those variable should be in all env files .

Answer (score 19):

Just a sidenote: Rails.env is special string object, that allows you to get current environment (its not like Rack's env):

```
puts Rails.env # => "production"
puts Rails.env.test? # => false
```

It's not meant to return config settings.

This may come in handy when you want to put your custom settings under `/config/initializers/*`, and for clarity, it's a better way in some cases (it's recommended not to clutter rails environment files with your custom settings). For example:

```
# config/initializers/mailer_settings.rb
if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    ...
  }
else
  #different settings
end
```

Comment: so, when application deployed to production, it will not pick config values form production.rb automatically?

Comment: and the smtp settings , i have added in development.rb, those also not pick from production.rb automatically?

Comment: @AnilD If you run Rails in produciont environment it will load configuration settings from app/environment.rb and app/environments/production.rb. So no, it will not pick settings from development.

Comment: that's what i need, i added all settings in production too :)

Comment: @AnilD For your custom settings and stuff like smtp you are encouraged to put those in config/initializers/<your_file.rb>. Take a look at this example: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast The /config/initializers/setup_mail.rb file will be automatically loaded. Here's where Rails.env comes in handy because you can create different setting for different environments.

Comment: @Ernest how is this better than putting it in production.rb?

Comment: @shime It's just matter of readability and organisation. The example I showed serves only as example, you could configure AM in production.rb too, but your custom stuff should definatetly go under initializers.